# Reloading Visual Studio Solution on branch change

Tags: visual-studio, github, gitkraken

Me and a friend are working on a Unreal project and we're using GitHub for our source control (with GitKraken).

I have created a few branches to keep work isolated. Just to test merging, etc. I created a class in my Programming branch and swapped branches just to see if the files didn't somehow go to all branches (just wanted to make sure I set up branches correctly). Luckily, the files don't go across branches.

However, I did notice in Visual Studio, the class files are still appearing in the Solution Explorer but they are not in the projects directory on my computer. I have Googled around and most people are saying about 'Reloading the solution', but I see no option to Reload the solution. I've tried re-building, compiling to see if the files go after compiling, tried tinkering with some options, including the .sln file in the commits (removed .sln from the .gitignore) and nothing seems to be working. I'm trying to work out how to stop visual studio from showing files in the solution explorer if they're not physically in the project. Just to avoid confusion when switching branches.

Any ideas?